# SQL errors only in Go-GORM Exec method

Tags: go-gorm

Has anyone dealt with handling database errors in GORM?

I have two cases in my code where I need to exploit a database error: constraint or UUID validation.
(e.g. SQL Error [8169] [S0002]: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.)

When I use the GORM model-find or raw-scan methods, I get the expected results in positive run, but in negative run result.error doesn’t include a SQL error (result.Error is nil), e.g. when I try to insert against a constraint or get with nonvalid UUID. I get this error in the SQL console with the same query.

On the other hand, when I use exec (also sql.Exec), I get an adequate error on a negative run, but the result of the positive run does not contain (or I can’t find) the expected value.
Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Please edit your post to add code that recreates the problem so we can help you.

Comment: [SOLUTION] Thank you very much and sorry for hussles - when I was extracting code, I found a solution. This is a combination of methods Exec and Find.